How to set up config parameters for local/global planner for simplified footprints robot using move_base in ROS Navigation stack?
I created simplified footprints combining a robot and the towing attachment.Then would like  try testing local and global planners on my environment using the created footprint. Here the navigation file
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<launch>
  <!-- Map Server -->
  <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="$(find robot_navigation)/maps/map.yaml"/>

  <!-- Static Transforms -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 0.1" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link 0.1" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_towing_attachment" args="0 -0.35 0 0 0 0 base_link towing_attachment 0.1" />


  <!-- Robot State Publisher -->
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" value="10.0" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find robot_navigation)/urdf/robot.urdf.xacro" />
  </node>

  <!-- Joint State Publisher (Optional for Visualization) -->
  <node pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" name="joint_state_publisher_gui" />

  <!-- Move Base Node -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <!-- Load costmap and planner parameters -->
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_navigation)/config/global_planner_params.yaml" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_navigation)/config/local_planner_params.yaml" />
    <rosparam file="$(find robot_navigation)/config/recovery_behaviors.yaml" />

    <param name="base_global_planner" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
  </node>

  <!-- RViz for Visualization -->
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find robot_navigation)/config/rviz_navigation_config.rviz" required="true" />
</launch>

Then the common_costmap.yaml
plugins:
  - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

footprint: [[-0.35, 0.35], [-0.35, -0.35], [0.35, -0.35], [0.35, 0.35], [0.6, 0.0]]
footprint_padding: 0.02

robot_radius: 0.2
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
inflation_radius: 0.55

global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: false  # Static map mode
  width: 30.0  # Adjust based on your map size
  height: 30.0
  resolution: 0.05

local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true  # Local window for dynamic updates
  width: 6.0  # Focus on the robot's immediate surroundings
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05

then the global
 NavfnROS:
      allow_unknown: true
      planner_patience: 5.0
      default_tolerance: 0.0
      use_dijkstra: true
      use_quadratic: true
      use_grid_path: false

and the local
DWAPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.5
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_vel_theta: -1.0
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_theta: 2.5
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1 # Increased for smoother stops
  sim_time: 1.5           # Increase simulation time for trajectory prediction
  vx_samples: 20          # More velocity samples for smoother path
  vtheta_samples: 40
  path_distance_bias: 32.0
  goal_distance_bias: 24.0
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  forward_point_distance: 0.2
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2

but then when run . It doesn't work. I got the eroors
[ERROR] [1732575210.871153814]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation 0.000094624s into the future.  Requested time 1732575210.870976925 but the latest data is at time 1732575210.870882273, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]

[ERROR] [1732575210.871405892]: Global Frame: odom Plan Frame size 502: map

[ WARN] [1732575210.871601034]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[ERROR] [1732575210.871734738]: Could not get local plan
[ INFO] [1732575210.920578331]: Got new plan

what can be the problem? Do i need an fake odometry node like this?
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Twist
import tf
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler

def publish_fake_odometry():
    rospy.init_node('fake_odometry', anonymous=True)
    odom_pub = rospy.Publisher('/odom', Odometry, queue_size=10)
    tf_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)  # 10 Hz
    x, y, theta = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # Simulate movement
        x += 0.1  # Move 0.1 m forward per cycle
        theta += 0.01  # Rotate slightly

        # Create quaternion for orientation
        q = quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, theta)

        # Publish odometry message
        odom = Odometry()
        odom.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        odom.header.frame_id = "odom"
        odom.child_frame_id = "base_link"

        odom.pose.pose.position.x = x
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = y
        odom.pose.pose.orientation.z = q[2]
        odom.pose.pose.orientation.w = q[3]

        odom.twist.twist.linear.x = 0.1
        odom.twist.twist.angular.z = 0.01

        odom_pub.publish(odom)

        # Broadcast TF from odom to base_link
        tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(
            (x, y, 0),
            q,
            rospy.Time.now(),
            "base_link",
            "odom"
        )

        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        publish_fake_odometry()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass

or some of the config files not correct?
